# How i can do ping and receive ms in method async in different class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, asynchronous, methods

Im trying call a method from other async class for get MS and put it in label...

This is my FormClass

```
    public SupremePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlatformStatus obj = new PlatformStatus();
        lblTest.Text = obj.Start();
    }
```

and here are my code in PlatformStatus class

```
class PlatformStatus
{
    string MS;
    public async Task<string> Start()
    {
        string GCIP1 = "45.164.124.103";

        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                PlatformStatus obj = new PlatformStatus();
                obj.GamersclubPing(GCIP1);

            });
        return MS;
    }


    public string GamersclubPing(string IPAddress)
    {
        Ping PingIt = new Ping();
        int iTiempoEspera = 2000;
        PingReply PingResponse;
        string GCBR2 = IPAddress;

        PingResponse = PingIt.Send(GCBR2, iTiempoEspera);
        if (PingResponse.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            MS = PingResponse.RoundtripTime.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MS = "-1";
        }
        return MS;
    }

}
```

i want put a string (IPAddress) in my FormClass and get Miliseconds from my PlatformStatus class...

I coded from 12 hours and i really dont idea how do this...

Comment: You can `await Ping.SendPingAsync` using this overload: [SendPingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_NetworkInformation_Ping_SendPingAsync_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Net_NetworkInformation_PingOptions_), to configure and execute the Ping, so you can remove almost everything you have there. You cannot `await` in a constructor. If that's a Form, use the `Form.Load` event, making it `async`, or whenever you need the results of a Ping.

Comment: i use `            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply =
            await ping.SendPingAsync("IPADDRESS");
            lblPingGCBR11.Text = pingReply.RoundtripTime.ToString();` for get miliseconds Async! thank you